# Can I see my other terminal open (tty) pwd?

Tags: unix, terminal, path

The goal is when I split my terminal screen to easily move to the same path.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not possible as long as both are open at the same time, they have no way to refresh..